# Java Stuck at a part of this assignment

Tags: java

This is my assignment:

> Modify the Week Two Java™ application using Java™ NetBeans™ IDE to meet these additional and changed business requirements:
>   - The company has recently changed its total annual compensation policy to improve sales.
>   - A salesperson will continue to earn a fixed salary of $75,000. The current sales target for every salesperson is $140,000.
>   - The sales incentive will only start when 80% of the sales target is met. The current commission is 25% of total sales.
>   - If a salesperson exceeds the sales target, the commission will increase based on an acceleration factor. The acceleration factor is 1.25.
>   - The application should ask the user to enter annual sales, and it should display the total annual compensation.
>   - The application should also display a table of potential total annual compensation that the salesperson could have earned, in $5000 increments above the salesperson's annual sales, until it reaches 50% above the salesperson's annual sales.

Everything works, the only thing I'm stuck at is having the table reach 50% of the salesperson's annuals sales. so for example if the total sales was $100,000 the table would show total sales and compensation until 150,000

Here is the source code

DriverCalculator.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class DriverCalculator {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        double annualSales;
        SalesPerson person;
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter your total sales for the year: ");
        annualSales=input.nextDouble();
        person=new SalesPerson(annualSales);
        System.out.println(" Your total compensation for the year: $"+String.format("%.2f", person.getTotalAnnualCompensation()));

        System.out.println("Total Sales              Total Compensation");
        annualSales= annualSales;
        for(int i=0;i<11;i++){
            person=new SalesPerson(annualSales);
             System.out.println("$"+ annualSales+"                "+"$"+String.format("%.2f", person.getTotalAnnualCompensation()));
            annualSales+=5000;
        }
    }
}
```

SalesPerson.java

```
public class SalesPerson {
// create variable (fixedSalary)
 double fixedSalary;
 // variable of the value of sale person's annual sales
 double  annualSales;
 //commission that is earned
 double commission;
 //The target for sales that must be reached by sales person
 double target;
 public SalesPerson(double annualSales){
     this.annualSales=annualSales;
     target=140000;
     commission=0;
     if(annualSales>target*0.8){
        if(annualSales<target)commission=0.25*annualSales;//The current commission 25% of total sales.
        else commission=0.25*1.25*annualSales;//The current commission (0.25*1.25)% of total sales.
     }
     fixedSalary=75000;// set fixed salary is 75000$
 }
 public double getTotalAnnualCompensation(){// calculate The total annual compensation is the fixed salary plus the commission earned
     return fixedSalary+commission;
 }
}
```

Comment: Driver Calculator.java

Comment: Why `i < 11`?  Maybe 11 is the correct limit if the person's sales are $100000, but it will not be correct for other cases.  Is that the problem?  I'm guessing that all the values it outputs are correct, but it just isn't outputting enough lines in the table (or is outputting too many)?

Comment: at a 100000 it  ouputs until 150000

Comment: yea it is def that line of code... what do i do to make it output to 50 % more than the annual sales

Comment: Something like `while (hypotheticalAnnualSales <= annualSales * 1.5) { ... }` instead of the `for` loop.  You don't need `i` anyway--you're not using it.  You do need to make sure to use a second variable, though, because you need to keep the original `annualSales` around to compute the upper limit.

Answer (score 0):

you need to dynamically calculate the upper limit of 'i' instead of hard coding. I think

```
annualSales= annualSales;
int upperlimit = (annualSales/2)/5000;
    for(int i=0;i<=upperlimit;i++){
        person=new SalesPerson(annualSales);
         System.out.println("$"+ annualSales+"                "+"$"+String.format("%.2f", person.getTotalAnnualCompensation()));
        annualSales+=5000;
      }
```

Comment: It only goes up to 145000 when inputting 100000so it was only 45% above the salespersons annual sales... I also input more numbers and they give output to 45 % above the salespersons annual sales

Comment: I tried testing it... its one short for every number i input... Anuswadh do you know why it is doing that?

Comment: Tests results:Please enter your total sales for the year: 100000
 Your total compensation for the year: $75000.00
Total Sales              Total Compensation
$100000.0                $75000.00
$110000.0                $75000.00
$120000.0                $105000.00
$130000.0                $107500.00
$140000.0                $118750.00
$150000.0                $121875.00
$160000.0                $125000.00
$170000.0                $128125.00
$180000.0                $131250.00
$190000.0                $134375.00
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)

Comment: sorry, its a coding mistake I did not add the upper limit itself in the for condition I am changing it